# VNC Tunnel over SSH

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, vncserver

I want to create a VNC connection over SSH from a client at home to a jump host at work. From the work private network I want to access to client through the jumphost. How to accomplish this. We already successfully set up the jump host for usage of an RDP connection over SSH at the work private network.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` has the `-D [bind_address:]port` option, which works by "allocating a socket to listen to port on the local side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address". I've found this very useful when used with `socksify`, otherwise known as `dante client`, which enforces the use of a SOCKS proxy for the program called in the command line. It would go something like this:

```
ssh -D 4547 user@server_ip_address
SOCKS_SERVER=127.0.0.1:4547 socksify xtightvncviewer server_ip_address
```

If host names are used instead of IP addresses and IPv6 is enabled it might not work as expected, and this is why I suggest the usage of IP addresses. IPv6 can be used with `dante`, though.

Comment: Can I use multiple clients with this setup? I should be used to remote support our at home working users.

Comment: As many ssh connections can be supported by the jump host. I've used this setup in a similar manner with ~20 clients and I don't think there will be any problem even with 100s of them.

Comment: And how do I connect from the work lan over the jump host to the vnc server running on the client?

Comment: You provide to the vnc client the actual address of the vnc server. Since it will be a socksified connection, the vnc server will see the connection coming from the jump host.